# Construct a triangle made up of squares in manim

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to create a right triangle made up of squares in `manim` see figure:

[image]

I was trying:

```
from manim import *

class blocks(Scene):
    def construct(self):
      for i in range(10):
         group = VGroup(*[Square(height=1,width=1)for s in range(i)])
         self.play(FadeIn(group[i]))
         copy = group[i].copy
         copy.next_to(group[i],RIGHT)
         group[i+1].next_to(copy,UP)
```

however this didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try using the `LaggedStartMap` animation:

```py
from manim import *


class BlockTriangle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        square_size = 0.5
        # Create a 0.5x0.5 square and fill it yellow.
        square = Square(side_length=square_size)
        square.set_fill(YELLOW, opacity=1)

        # Create a VGroup to hold all the rows of squares.
        squares = VGroup()
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(i):
                # Add a copy of the square shifted to the right
                # and down by the appropriate amount, given by
                # the loop variables i and j.
                squares.add(square.copy().shift(
                    # Multiply by square_size to get the correct
                    # spacing, since LEFT and DOWN are unit vectors.
                    square_size * (LEFT * j + DOWN * i)
                ))
        
        # Move the squares to the center of the screen
        squares.move_to(ORIGIN)
        # Fade in the squares one by one with LaggedStartMap
        self.play(LaggedStartMap(FadeIn, squares, lag_ratio=0.2, run_time=4))
        self.wait()
```

You can check the generated animation here:

[Construct a triangle with blocks - Manim CE](https://imgur.com/a/NwGIa07)